# Can't do multitask, creates errors?

Tags: c#

My program works as followed:

Its a program that you can shutdown a server, it has multiple trigger events.
you have to set a time for the actual countdown in the program to see it in the game printed.

(example)

if you click 1 hour (maintenance) in game cast would say there will be a maintenance in 1 hour.
then you select (15minutes) maintenance duration. (automatic maintenance).
you press shutdown, triggers start to walk off.

at a point a trigger starts the worker, where the actual work begins.
although... it's working but not the way I want it to.

I want it to do:

(do_this first)
(wait for this to finish and confirm that the database connection got closed)
(do next function on the list)
and so on.

currently the code looks like :

```
    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            //Create Thread for multitask
            Thread Del_Char_Related_WORKER = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Del_Char_Related));
            Thread Del_Null_Item_WORKER = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Del_Null_Item));

            //Start Multitask
              Del_Char_Related_WORKER.Start();

              Del_Null_Item_WORKER.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Worker Got Tired of Working.");
        }
        

    }
```

once I execute the program, all events work except the worker, (it works but gets stuck at the first job, he finishes it. but than he keeps looping job 1 while I have 2 jobs listed.

Also, when it starts the first job, it gives me the exception error which is in the first job.

(first job)

```
    void Del_Char_Related()
    {
        if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                string connect = string.Format("Data Source={0},{1};Initial Catalog={2};User Id={3};Password={4};",
                OPT.GetString("db.server"),
                OPT.GetString("db.port"),
                OPT.GetString("db.name"),
                OPT.GetString("db.account"),
                SFM.GetDecryptMD5(OPT.GetString("db.password"));

                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connect);
                sqlcon.Open();
                new SqlCommand("DECLARE @Rows INT,@sid INT,@acc_id INT SET @Rows = 1 WHILE (@Rows > 0) BEGIN SET @sid = (SELECT TOP(1) sid FROM dbo.Character WHERE name LIKE '%@%') SET @acc_id = (SELECT TOP(1) account_id FROM dbo.Character WHERE name LIKE '%@%') DELETE TOP (1) FROM dbo.Character WHERE name LIKE '%@%' SET @Rows = (SELECT count(sid) FROM dbo.Character WHERE name LIKE '%@%') DELETE FROM dbo.Item  WHERE owner_id = @sid OR account_id = @acc_id DELETE FROM dbo.ItemCoolTime WHERE owner_id = @sid DELETE FROM dbo.State WHERE owner_id = @sid DELETE FROM dbo.Quest WHERE owner_id = @sid DELETE FROM dbo.QuestCoolTime WHERE owner_id = @sid DELETE FROM dbo.Skill WHERE owner_id = @sid DELETE FROM dbo.Guild where leader_id = @sid END", sqlcon).ExecuteNonQuery();
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                sqlcon.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Ive completed my duty (TASK1)");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (OPT.GetString("db.port") == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to detect a PORT!");
                }
                MessageBox.Show("No OPT detected or OPT command incorrect!");
            }
        }
    }
```

so kind of got a weird situation that I just can't get out of.

it works, but gets looped at job1, than also t keeps saying ''No OPT detected or command incorrect'' while everything on the encrypted opt file is correct.
(this worked before, but I don't want 2 sql commands being launched at the same time cause of the risk of deadlocks could disconnect the server.)

Comment: Well first of all your question title is *far* too vague, "*Can't do multitask, creates errors*" - what errors exactly, which lines? Also what class/object is `OPT`?

Comment: the OPT section works fine, the error i get is from the exception of job1. ''No OPT detected or OPT command incorrect!'', but at the same time he says he has completed job1. and he truely has done that.

Comment: "*It keeps saying `No OPT detected or command incorrect`*" - which means an exception is occurring, have you checked to see which *particular* exception it is? At a start you could take the `Message` property from the exception rather than outputting your own, it may give you a hint as to what is going on. Also, it's generally never a good idea to catch `Exception` anyway as it's *far* too general you should be catching specific exceptions which you can handle.

Comment: how do i get it to give me specific error values than? is there a code for it ^^?

Comment: change "catch (Exception)" to "catch (Exception ex)" and breakpoint on the next if statement, then have a look at what ex contains (right click ex, click quick watch)

Comment: Add an exception variable into the catch statement i.e. `catch (Exception ex)` and inspect the `ex` object. It will give you the *real* exception type and all the relevant callstack information etc.

Comment: Okay, i done what you said somehow the error comes from Job2.

Comment: Fixed the error, but now i still have to know, how do i make the program to wait for one job to finish before it starts the next one?

Comment: Don't create a thread for each task, but only one thread that sequentially performs the tasks. *Do not show message boxes from threads!!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are swallowing your exception, so to speak, by just showing an arbitrary message. Instead, make use of the `Exception` instance provided in the `catch`:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Although, I wouldn't necessarily condone throwing up dialogs, you can use the debugger to break in the `catch` block, interrogate stuff and things, and correct the problem.

Comment: Already changed it, but thanks!

maybe you know how i make it do one task and than do another task and add a sort of wait function between these 2?

( no thread.sleep ) cause that will bug the program / stuck

Comment: If you've changed it and got the message, then tell us the error.

Comment: I've fixed the error already myself, the issue is that it launches 2 functions at the exact same time, so what i need is that it only starts one function when that function is done it should start the next and so on.

Comment: Well then that's a different question. Also, then what is the point of using multiple threads?

Comment: I wanted to launch the threads in order, but apperently its not working.

like, start 1. complete 1. wait for 1 to close database. start2.